# SysCmd(SYSCMD_INIFILE) not returning correct ini path in Office 365 Access

Tags: vba, ms-access, windows-10, vb6, office365

I'm trying to move an old vb6 application from Windows 2003 to Windows 10.
There's this access reports database that is called by the vb6 app using parameters that looks like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\Office\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\TestApp\AccessDb_ap.mdb" 
/wrkgrp "C:\TestApp\AccessDb_sc.mdw" 
/ini "C:\TestApp\AccessDb.ini" 
/nostartup 
/user some_guy
```

When the access db is being initialized, there's this line in some module:

```
sFile = SysCmd(SYSCMD_INIFILE)
```

The `sFile` is assigned `"C:\TestApp\AccessDb.ini"` path correctly in Win 2003 (that has Office 2003).

In the same line in Windows 10 (Office 365),

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\MSACCESS.EXE" "C:\TestApp\AccessDb_ap.mdb" 
/wrkgrp "C:\TestApp\AccessDb_sc.mdw" 
/ini "C:\TestApp\AccessDb.ini" 
/nostartup 
/user some_guy
```

The `sFile` variable is assigned empty string instead of the ini path.
Is `SysCmd(SYSCMD_INIFILE)` not relevant anymore in Office 365 Access Db? How do I resolve this?
I wasn't able to find this information on the internet so turning to SO for help.
Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The `/ini` command-line switch is deprecated since Office '95 ([source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/command-line-switches-for-microsoft-office-products-079164cd-4ef5-4178-b235-441737deb3a6#ID0EAABAAA=Access)), and afaik completely removed since 2007 onwards.

If you want to load a specific profile, use the `/profile` switch  and create the appropriate profile in registry.

If that command-line switch is used for something else, well, tough luck, you can't expect something that has been deprecated over 25 years ago to continue working indefinitely. You'll have to adjust the application. And while you're at it, you might want to consider that user-level security with MDW files has been shown to be easily bypassible and has also been deprecated for over 10 years

Comment: Hi Erik, How do I accomplish this? Good thing the `/ini` switch is used only for pointing the `.ini` file. Can you please provide an example to do this using /profile switch? I'm so very new to VBA. Thank You!

Comment: Sorry, but I can't, with the details you've currently provided. The steps would be: check how the ini file is used (`SysCmd(SYSCMD_INIFILE)` is odd, you pretty much never do stuff with the ini file), and check how to do that without the ini file, then check what's in the ini file, write that to a profile, and use that profile with the profile switch. Or, if you feel like going rogue, just replace `SysCmd(SYSCMD_INIFILE)` with `"C:\TestApp\AccessDb.ini"` and pray nothing breaks.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. How do I create a profile, and write `.ini` settings to it? And if I pass the profile name using that switch, how do I access those settings in the code? I'll also try replacing `SysCmd(SYSCMD_INIFILE)`. Thank you!

Comment: Yeah, sorry, this is as far as I go, most of these questions you've asked require quite a bit of work and can't be answered in comments here.

Comment: I would adopt the standard that the .ini is assumed to be in the same folder/location as the applicaiton. You can then use: CurrentProject.Path & "\AccessDB.ini". and if you followed a standard of naming the .ini the SAME as the database, then You couldl use both the current name and .ini file extension. That way you don't hard code the name nor the location of the .ini file in your code. So, MyIniFile = replace(currentdb.name,".accDB",".ini") would get the .ini file of the same name, and in the same location.  and if this is to run as accDE or accDB, then don't even hard code that!

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal. I saved my old `.mdb` database as `.accdb`, changed the `.ini` filename to `AccessDb_ap.ini` instead of the original `AccessDb.ini`. After that used your line: `sFile = Replace(CurrentDb.Name, ".accdb", ".ini")` to get the `.ini` file. It works like a charm. Thank you so much!